# DFP advertisements no longer opening in gmail

Tags: html, email, gmail, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

We have been using DFP (Double Click for Publishers Small Business) to display ads in HTML emails for about a year. We are aware that they are not supported in HTML emails but up until lately, they have been working well.

Recently, the ads only open a blank browser tab when opened in Gmail. Emails that are delivered to other email providers, outlook.com, yahoo, etc... are still working correctly.

We are using the following markup within our HTML emails for the advertisements:

```html
<a href="https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/jump?iu=/1375616/bxx_728x90_A&amp;sz=728x90&amp;t=&amp;c=[timestamp]&amp;co=1"><img alt="" src="https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ad?iu=/1375616/bxx_728x90_A&amp;sz=728x90&amp;t=&amp;c=[timestamp]&amp;co=1" style="max-width: 630px;" /> </a>
```

In the past, the co=1 url variable is what seemed to make these work. The same ads spots delivered to a webpage work fine. It just seems to be an issue in Gmail. Any ideas on what is causing this issue or how I might be able to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

As email ads our not supported by DFP we ended up switching to Live Intent and no longer are facing these issues.